# How to code post suggestions

Tags: html

I am currently working on building my first website since I started learning coding. I want the page to suggest posts to the user such as Most read, Recent posts etc. How do I code this? Is there a video you can suggest to help me learn this?

Comment: I think google is the best place for this kind of questions.

Comment: I presume you are trying to build a blog website. In that case, you'll need a language that powers the back end of site and allow it to push data to the front end, such as `Ruby`, `Python`, `PHP`, `AngularJS` and `Javascript`. You can get plenty of tutorials from YouTube.

Comment: Thank you Muhammad. I have tried searching on google and youtube but the search results do not show me want I want. I just wasn't searching with the right words because I do not know what words to use. But I know humans here would understand what I mean. That's why I asked here.

Could you please direct me to materials that can help me. I would be much easier to continue search from then on, on my own. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should give us something so we can answer you. You want static site or dynamic? What CMS (WordPress, Joomla, ...) are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this depends on how you intend to approach the solution. For any language you are using, the following are things to consider:

1. When you say **Most read**, that means a post is associated with a counter the keeps track of the times its been clicked.
2. However, **Recent post** means, the date of the post is within whatever duration you specified.

So, when you want the page to suggest some post to a user, I assume somewhere in your page there is a lister or block that shows these recommended post.

Therefore, what you should simply do is:

1. Create a function that retrieves all the post and determines those post with the highest count (*meaning most read or most clicked*).
2. Also, in the same function, determine if the post date is within the days you consider to be recent. Meaning, ***today's date*** minus ***the post date*** = **days of post**. If it is less than 10 for example, then the post is recent.
3. Once you finish evaluating these criteria, consume all relevant post in a list or an array.
4. Finally, return the list containing all relevant post (_ids) that passes those criteria.
5. Display the list to the user.

Since this is your first website, try and write the code yourself instead of someone giving you a written lines of code. This will make you better and you will know how the bits and pieces work.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I will commence work using this guideline. I greatly appreciate your comment.

Comment: Cheers. You can accept my answer then.

Comment: I just did. Thanks again.